# Radius of convergence (complex) - Ratio test vs. Root test

Tags: complex-analysis

Starting to learn convergence of a power series in complex analysis, and I was given two tests (and my lecture didn't differentiate between the usefulness of the two) which were the Ratio Test and the Root Test.

### Information/Notes I have

For a complex power series
$$S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n (z-z_0)^n$$

Denote the radius of convergence as $\rho$, then the root test tells us that
$$\rho = (\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup(|a_n|^\frac{1}{n})))^{-1}.$$

Then also (if it does exist), by the Ratio Test,
$$\rho=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$$
which is (to me) a much easier limit to find.
I read this: [Radius of convergence and ratio test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331770/radius-of-convergence-and-ratio-test)
and people say that if I could find $\rho$ by the ratio test, I could have done so by the Root Test as well. It seems much harder though, and I'm not sure if I understand it (I'm using W|A to calculate the supremum here).

### Question in specific

$$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(n+1)(n^2+2)}{2^n}(z+3)^n$$
The ratio test immediately shows that the radius of convergence $\rho$ is equal to $2$. However, I'm not sure how I would have used the Root Test here, and W|A doesn't seem to validate my answer by the Ratio Test... (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=supremum+of+(n(n%2B1)(n%5E2%2B2)%2F2%5En)%5E1%2Fn).
I was wondering if someone could clear up whether or not I'm supposed to be able to do it by the Root Test (even if it's computationally harder here) or did I just get some definition mixed up?

Comment: But $$\left(\frac{n(n+1)(n^2+2)}{2^n}\right)^{-1/n}\to2$$ so where is the problem?

Comment: The choice of using ratio/root test is based on which would be computationally easier. You won't get different answers with both. Usually, root test is used when there is $n$ in the power.

Comment: Oh, and of course, the root test always work while the ratio test works only in some restricted cases.

Comment: @DId Why did you only look at the $|a_n|$ term? How come the $\lim \sup$ operation disappeared?

Comment: @SahibaArora I was under the impression that some cases the Ratio Test wouldn't give as "accurate" (if any) answer than if we used the Root Test for some reason. e.g. in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331770/radius-of-convergence-and-ratio-test?noredirect=1&lq=1, the top reply, I did the ratio test and found the limit to be infinity, whilst they calculated it by the Root Test to be $3$.

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours Actually, I computed $$\lim|a_n|^{-1/n}$$ Of course, when this limit exists, it is also $$\frac1{\lim|a_n|^{1/n}}=\frac1{\limsup|a_n|^{1/n}}$$ but the main advantage of the root test is when the limit does not exist, only the limsup.

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours **If** the ratio test is applicable, it gives the same answer as the root test. But the ratio test is only applicable in special circumstances.

Comment: @DanielFischer What kind of circumstances would they be?

Comment: Only finitely many coefficients may be zero, and *the limit of the quotients must exist*. When the ratio test works, it's often simpler/easier to apply than the root test. But the root test always works, while the ratio test doesn't.